# Spectrogram for created signal in Octave

Tags: fft, matlab, spectrogram, stft, octave

I'm trying to test the `specgram` function located in the signal package in octave but I'm a little confused at the variables in `specgram`.  What I would like to do is be able to get the `specgram` data into an array that will show the frequency and the length of time when the frequency starts and stops.

See example code below: I was trying to get the array to show that for the length of `t1` will be $7 \textrm{ Hz}$, `t2` will be $12\textrm{ Hz}$ and for `t3` will be $2\textrm{ Hz}$.  How can I go about doing this?

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and octave 3.2.4 and the signal pacakage 1.0.11

```
% combines sig with spectra plot
clear all,clc,tic;
fs=1000;
t1=linspace(0,2*pi,fs/0.1); %need to round off no decimals
t2=linspace(0,2*pi,fs/0.3); %need to round off no decimals
t3=linspace(0,2*pi,fs/0.6); %need to round off no decimals

%Create signal in different arrays
y1=sin(7*t1);
y2=sin(12*t2);
y3=sin(2*t3);

%append arrays to test specgram
yt = [y1 y2 y3];


%plot(yt) %will show combined plot

%Spectrum section
yts=specgram(yt',20,500, 2,1);
plot(yts)
fprintf('\nfinally Done-elapsed time -%4.4fsec- or -%4.4fmins- or -%4.4fhours-\n',toc,toc/60,toc/3600);
```

Comment: It looks like you are effectively changing the sample rate when you go from t1 to t2 to t3.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: I tried the code above in octave, and it does not work. Also, when using 'specgram(x)' instead i does display a spectrogram, but the frequencies are not right. does anybody know how to get them right?

Comment: Write new question! Write what is "code above", write what is "are not right" and what is "get them right".

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
fs = 100;
t = 0:1/fs:10;
x = [sin(2*pi*7*t), sin(2*pi*12*t), sin(2*pi*2*t)];
specgram(x,256,1000, [],200);
```

I have reduced the sampling frequency because the three frequencies in your signal are quite low. In the specgram() function, I have increased the FFT size to 256 and used the default hanning(256) window with 200/256 $\approx$ 80% overlap.
[image: You can see three horizontal lines at the three frequencies of interest.]